# How to rerender v-data-table on VueJS 2

Tags: vuejs2, rerender, v-data-table

I have a v-data-table. On a pop up, I select a few of the columns of the table and combine these values and add them back to the table as a new column.
My problem is, I can't re-render the v-data-table after I clicked my Save button. I tried $forceUpdate but didn't work. What can i use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty weird it doesn't get rerendered automatically. But one solution could be to assign your data an empty array (I assume it's an array) and right after it put:

```
tabledata = []; // empty your data here
Vue.nextTick(function () {
   tabledata = [0,1,2]; // assign your new data here
})
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick